Custom code for Live Agent Chat in salesforce experience cloud
I'm working on creating a semi custom Live Agent Chat functionality using Apex. I need to create chat requests and make them appear in omni-channel just like the standard functionality. I have to create a custom component which works almost exactly like the standard functionality and using standard objects.
I have inserted a LiveChatVisitor and LiveChatTranscript but they are not showing up in the omni-channel.
Can anyone help..?
